# How to get normal terminal behavior for directories when executing a custom shell script?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to know a way to mimic the behavior in terminal when you cd in to a directory structure in shell script.

ex: When you type partial name of the directory and hit tab the directory name is completed.

Can this be achieved when executing a custom shell script as well? I tried to find this in the internet with no luck.

Comment: search for "bash custom command completion"... it is possible, but not an very simple task....

Comment: If you just want to autocomplete paths you can normally do that with just the default Bash completion - simply type the command and follow it with a path. If not you need to be more specific and include the code you have so far.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'll look in to this more.